# H3 tag moved under HR line

Tags: html, css

Why my `<h3>` tag is under `<hr/>`line?

```
<section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
    <h3 class="pull-left">{{article.title}}</h3>
    <hr/>
    <p>{{article.title}}</p>
</section>
```

Screenshot: http://take.ms/nVf0C9

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: As you have same text for your `<h3>` and `<p>` tags, it could be `<p>` tag and `<h3>` tag is somewhat hidden

Comment: @Lal I'm sorry, h3 tag. I'll try to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pull-left will have a float on it

`<hr style="clear:both">`

Should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the class 'pull-left' on your h3 tag which i'm assuming has float: left css property set.

Comment: And how can I fix it without removing class?

Comment: Add style='float: none' to the h3 tag. This will override the css float.

Comment: You could also add style='clear: both' to the hr tag.